# How do I change all of the font sizes in a div?

Tags: javascript, css

First of all I apologize for my English. If the editors fix my mistakes, I'm happy.

Here my div and content.

```
<div data-x="182" data-y="201" class="resize-drag" contenteditable="true" id="text-giris2"  style="width: 115px; height: 153px; transform: translate(182px, 201px); position: absolute; text-align: left; overflow: hidden; border: 1px solid black;">
    <u style="font-size: 15px;">asd</u>
    as a<b>sd</b>
    <span>a<span style="color: red; font-size: 18px;">s a</span>sdas a
    <span><span style="font-size: 18px;">sdasd 
    <span style="font-size: 26px;">addddddd</span></span></span></span>
    </div>
```

I want to dynamically change the sizes of all the font sizes in the div element with the unique name "text-input2". But what will happen in it is not clear. As above, tags like `<span>`, `<u>`, `<b>` can be similar. I want to take 2 times the size of all the fonts I want to do. As an example, I would like to have `<span style = "font-size: 18px>` after the `<span style =" font-size: 36px>` Similarly, `<u style = "font-size: 15px;">` after the `<u style = "font-size: 30px;">` Can such a thing be done using only CSS? If it is impossible, I will try to do with Javascript, but I did not know where to start. I am waiting for your help. Thank you.

Comment: Is JQuery allowed?

Comment: ye Of course . @TobyMellor

Comment: you want css for this only or there can be more possibilities?

Comment: .resize-drag u{ font-size:36px !important} , .resize-drag span{ font-size:36px !important} , .resize-drag span:last-child{ font-size:52px !important}

Comment: The elements in the div may vary. It has to be something dynamic. So for every element that has the font size property.@SahilDhir

Comment: I want to make 20px if the "u" element or "span" element font size is 10px. So there will not be a fixed definition.

Comment: You want to doubele the size?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142723/discussion-between-muhammet-can-tonbul-and-sahil-dhir).

Comment: @MuhammetCanTONBUL My solution simply doubles the font size. Please let me know if this is not what you meant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code I've provided below will loop through all of the elements contained within the div with the id `text-giris2`. On each iteration, it will take the current font size and double it.

```
$('#text-giris2').children().css('font-size', function(i, current){
    return parseFloat(current) * 2;
});
```

**An example**

```js
$('#container').children().css('font-size', function(i, current){
    console.log('New font size for ' + $(this).text() + ' is ' + parseFloat(current) * 2);
    return parseFloat(current) * 2;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <span style="font-size: 5px;">Hello</span>
    <p style="font-size: 7px;">World</p>
    <span>Foobar</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Ty sir you save my day :)

Comment: You could rewrite (for brevity) as: `$('#container').children().css('font-size', function(i, current){ return parseFloat(current) * 2; });` as jQuery's setter methods iterate over every element in the collection the use of `each()` isn't required, and the `this` in the anonymous function refers to the current DOM node, while `current` variable refers to the current value (before manipulation) of the property to be set, or updated.

Comment: @DavidThomas Works like a charm! Thanks for the suggestion, I didn't know this